# How does callback functions work in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, callback

Considering the following code:

rectangle.js:

```
module.exports = (x,y,callback) => {
    if (x <= 0 || y <= 0)
        setTimeout(() => 
            callback(new Error("Rectangle dimensions should be greater than zero: l = "
                + x + ", and b = " + y), 
            null),
            2000);
    else
        setTimeout(() => 
            callback(null, {
                perimeter: () => (2*(x+y)),
                area:() => (x*y)
            }), 
            2000);
}
```

index.js:

```
var rect = require('./rectangle');

function solveRect(l,b) {
    console.log("Solving for rectangle with l = "
                + l + " and b = " + b);
    rect(l,b, (err,rectangle) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", err.message);
        }
        else {
            console.log("The area of the rectangle of dimensions l = "
                + l + " and b = " + b + " is " + rectangle.area());
            console.log("The perimeter of the rectangle of dimensions l = "
                + l + " and b = " + b + " is " + rectangle.perimeter());
        }
    });
    console.log("This statement after the call to rect()");
};

solveRect(2,4);
solveRect(3,5);
solveRect(0,5);
solveRect(-3,5);
```

In this line `rect(l,b, (err,rectangle)` we call the `rect` function and pass `l,b, err,rectangle` to it. I can see what are `l,b` but can't see and understand what are `err, rectangle` ?

Also can't understand where is the definition of `callback` function? Is it an inner function?

Comment: `callback` is a parameter to the `rect` function, and its value is the `(err, rectangle) => ...` function that you supply as an argument.

Comment: It's no different from the way `x` and `y` get assigned from the function arguments.

Comment: `err` and `rectangle` are the parameters to the anonymous function in `index.js`.

Comment: You're passing those arguments when you invoke callback inside rectangle.js.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the arrow function notation? `(err, rectangle) => {...}` is similar to `function(err, rectangle) {...}`

Comment: In this line `rect(l,b, (err,rectangle)` we call the `rect` function and pass `l,b, err,rectangle` to it. I can see what are `l,b` but can't see and understand what are `err, rectangle` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow notation can be confusing here, especially since it takes up most of the `rect` function call. It is equivalent to

```
var callback = function(err,rectangle){
  if(err) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // do stuff
  }
};

rect(l,b, callback);
```

When we call `rect(l,b, callback)` inside of index.js, it calls the function inside of rectangle.js, passing in a reference to the function in index.js (which i named callback above). This means that when rectangle calls `callback(new Error( ...` it is passing in an `Error` object to the callback defined in index.js. And when it calls `callback(null, ...` it is passing `null` for the err parameter and the rectangle object for the rectangle parameter in `callback`.

At the moment we call `rect(l,b, callback)` we don't have the err or rectangle parameters though, javascript just knows it's passing a function that takes 2 parameters.

Comment: How we pass `err,rectangle` from inside of the `index.js` when they must be calculate inside of the `rectangle.js` and we don't have them inside of the `index.js`?

Comment: I mean we pass two parameters from `index.js` to `rectangle.js` that we don't have them at the moment and they must be calculated inside of the `rectangle.js`. So how we passed them?

Comment: let me know if you're still confused :)

Comment: As I guessed and understood, it's something like a 2 step function call. In first step it only passes the `l,b` parameters from `index.js` to `rectangle.js`, then in the `rectangle.js` it will calculate `error,rectangle` considering what are the `l,b` and will pass them to `index.js` again. And in the second step, `index.js` using this `err,rectangle` and passing them again to `rectangle.js` to calculate error message or area and perimeter.

Answer (score 1):

Callback is nothing but the concept of passing a function as a parameter in function call like `solveRect(2,4, fn)`. Here `fn` is going to be a function.

You can define it inline:

```
solveRect(2,4, function(err,rectangle){
   // your code to handle response or delayed result
});
```

Or as named function:

```
let fn = function(err,rectangle){
   // your code to handle response or delayed result
}
solveRect(2,4,fn)
```

Comment: In this line `rect(l,b, (err,rectangle)` we call the `rect` function and pass `l,b, err,rectangle` to it. I can see what are `l,b` but can't see and understand what are `err, rectangle` ?

Comment: Wherever you will call `callback` from `rectangle.js:` parameters passed in function call `callback` as parameter will be error and rectangle respectively.